# Adding a character in a specific position in a string

Tags: python, excel, vba

I exported appointments from Outlook to Excel.

The dates are in the following format:
552020
652020
752020
752020
7102020
9102020
11102020

We have 3 variations:

1. Date with 1 number for day and month
2. Date with singular day and double digit month
3. Date with double digit day and month.

I would like to add "." after day and month, so that the output would be:

5.5.2020
6.5.2020
7.5.2020
7.5.2020
7.10.2020
9.10.2020
11.10.2020

Is this possible with Python or Excel VBA?

I tried some of the Excel functions like changing the cell to a "Date" and such but it does not give the correct date as output.

---

I do not have any date related to January, earliest date in my case would be May.
11102020 would be the 11th of November

Comment: And `1112020` would be in January or in November?

Comment: what you are trying to do is not logical. for example, how will you split 1112020? 1.11.2020 or 11.1.2020? both are true. you should do it while exporting from outlook to excel.

Comment: I do not have any date related to January, earliest date in my case would be May. 11102020 would be the 11th of November

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a `IF loop` to test what bucket your number falls into. Keep in mind this code will not work correctly if you have January or February data!

```
Sub DateConvert()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim DateYear As Long
Dim DateDay As Long
Dim DateMonth As Long
Dim TotalLength As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim loop1 As Long

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For loop1 = 1 To LastRow
    TotalLength = Len(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value)
    DateYear = Right(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, 4)
    DateRest = Len(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4))
    
    If DateRest = 4 Then
        DateDay = Left(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 2)
        DateMonth = Right(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 2)
    ElseIf DateRest = 2 Then
        DateDay = Left(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 1)
        DateMonth = Right(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 1)
    Else
        DateMonth = Right(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 2)
        
        If DateMonth = 10 Or DateMonth = 11 Or DateMonth = 12 Then
            DateDay = Left(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 1)
        Else
            DateMonth = Right(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 1)
            DateDay = Left(Left(ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value, TotalLength - 4), 2)
        End If
    End If
    
    ws.Cells(loop1, 1).Value = DateDay & "." & DateMonth & "." & DateYear
Next loop1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not never have the case like 12.5.2020 (day is two digit and month is one), you can do :

```
not_formated = "11102020"

if len(not_formated) == 6:
    print(not_formated[0] + '.' + not_formated[1] + '.' + not_formated[2:])
if len(not_formated) == 7:
    print(not_formated[0] + '.' + not_formated[1:3] + '.' + not_formated[3:])
if len(not_formated) == 8:
    print(not_formated[:2] + '.' + not_formated[2:4] + '.' + not_formated[4:])
```

Comment: not_formated  = '1152020'.  Does your code work for this ?

The len is 7 and your code will give 1.15.2020 as answer, which is incorrect

Comment: It does not work for case where month is single digit and day double digit as I said.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example: I want to write date 25122020 in python 2.7.8

```
var date = 25.12.2020
print("The date is "+ date +"in an example")
```

Comment: Hi,

In Python you need to declare strings differently, like so :

`date = "25.12.2020"`